# Is recursively computing pow(x, n) better than brute force?

Tags: java, algorithm

I see when people implement `pow(x,n)`, they always use similar solutions below. My confusion is, what is the advantage of below solution comparing just brute force multiple x for n times?

```
public class Solution {
    public double pow(double x, int n) {
        if(n == 0)
            return 1;
        if(n<0){
            n = -n;
            x = 1/x;
        }
        return (n%2 == 0) ? pow(x*x, n/2) : x*pow(x*x, n/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Less iterations. It takes advantage that `(x^a)^b == x^(a*b)` (where `^` is the power operation).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, what do you mean less iterations? Do you mean my code posted or some other implementations?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I see no evidence of that general property being used. All I see is the usage of one special case: x^n = (x^2)^(n/2).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik while that's true, consider that checking for that general property at all times would require checking every prime number between 2 and sqrt(n), which wouldn't be an O(1) operation.  Also, in programming, we frequently deal with powers of 2, so this is a good optimization to make most a lot of the time.

Comment: @soong Seems like you think I complained about it not being used, but I didn't. Using its full strength would not substantially improve the runtime (it would remain logarithmic). Also note that there is room between the fully general property and just one special case: you might for example add a step by 3 and 5.

Comment: @soong For powers of two, the JRE already provides a fast method: Math.powerOfTwoD(int).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't think adding one for 3 would actually help, as MattPutnam's answer points out that x^3 would do x*x^2 in the recursive call. As for Durandal, this strikes me as an educational exercise or an interview question, for which using the existing JRE libraries would be inappropriate (I suspect the JRE's Math.pow() is already more optimized than the example here).

Comment: @soong I wasn't really making a practical suggestion, just an observation. Especially note that division by anything but a power of two is significantly slower.

Comment: @LinMa, you start off with "I see when people implement"...  Actually in real life this algorithm is always implemented iteratively, not with recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quicker.

Suppose you do `pow(3, 8)`.

This calls `pow(9, 4)`.

This, in turn, calls `pow(81, 2)`.

Then `pow(6561, 1)`.

This is our first odd power, so this time we do `6561 * pow(43046721, 0)` and we get our final answer of `6561`.

(It would probably be better if `pow(6561, 1)` just returned `6561` rather than computing `43046721`).

This has only required four multiplications, compared to the obvious solution which requires seven. In general, it reduces the time complexity from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`. Here `n` is the power, not the base.

Answer (score 6):

This technique is formally known as [*Exponentiation by squaring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). It requires fewer operations than "flat" exponentiation by repeated multiplication, so the result of N<sup>k</sup> is computed in log<sub>2</sub>k time.

Note that although the *implementation* of this algorithm is usually recursive, it does not have to be done this way. An algorithm can be re-written with iterations instead of recursion, to produce the same speed up:

```
public static double pow(double x, int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    double y = 1;
    while (n > 1) {
        if (n%2 == 1) {
            y *= x;
        }
        x *= x;
        n /= 2;
    }
    return x*y;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qgccSg)

Comment: There's something not quite right here. I tried `pow(2, 10)` and got `6.7108864E7`.

Comment: An aside: you don't need this `n = (n-1)/2;` but just `n /= 2` for both cases (outside if-then-else).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It was `n > 0` instead of `n > 1`.

Comment: Hm, fascinating. I didn't anticipate an off-by-one would disturb the return value by more than the square of correct value.

Comment: For performance it's safer to use `n & 1` instead of `n % 2` and `n >>= 1` instead of `n /= 2`. HotSpot's C2 undoubtedly takes care of those (probably C1 as well), but less sophisticated runtimes may not.

Answer (score 4):

This algorithm runs in O(log(n)) time, rather than O(n) time.  If `n` is even, it divides the remaining work to be done in half, by making use of the identity `x^n = (x^2)^(n/2)`.  If `n` is odd, it has to do a standard multiplication, but then `n` will be even on the next iteration, so it all averages out to log(n) time in the end.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have logarithmic complexity as opposed to linear complexity when simply multiplying `x * x * x * x * ...`.

In the end it will result in lower number of steps necessary (for higher x this will be very significant).

For example simply linear approach `x^8` would result in eight steps:

```
step1 = x
step2 = x * step1
step3 = x * step2
step4 = x * step3
step5 = x * step4
step6 = x * step5
step7 = x * step6
step8 = x * step7
return step8
```

The presented version does basically this:

```
step1 = x
step2 = step1 * step1 // equal to x * x
step3 = step2 * step2 // equal to x * x * x * x
step4 = step3 * step3 // equal to x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x
return step4
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can easily find out by looking at this piece of code, the **algorithmic complexity** of this function is **`O(log2(n))`**, while the *natural* implementation would result in (roughly) **`n`** operations.

---

Considering that:

```
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    if(n < 0){
        n = -n;
        x = 1/x;
    }
```

is a **constant complexity (`O(1)`)**, the only part of the algorithm that is impacted in any way by the power at which you want to elevate your input is the following:

```
    if (n%2 == 0) {
        return pow(x*x, n/2);
    } else {
        return x*pow(x*x, n/2);
    }
```

In either case, you notice here that each iteration through that method will result in another until `n` reaches `0`. It's also blatant here that, using this algorithm, `n` will decrease at a **logarithmic** pace.

For example, `2^1024` calculated this way would result in roughly 10 iterations:

```
pow(2, 1024);
\_pow(4, 512);
  \_pow(16, 256);
    \_pow(256, 128);
      \_pow(65536, 64);
        \_pow(..., 32);
          \_pow(..., 16);
            \_pow(..., 8);
              \_pow(..., 4);
                \_pow(..., 2);
                  \_pow(..., 1);
```

... thus totalling roughly **10** actual operations, instead of **1024** with the **natural** implementation.